# Prevent searched zsh command history from being deleted?

Tags: shell, unix, zsh, oh-my-zsh

Sometimes, I use ^P to look up previous commands. I find the command I'm looking for, and it could be a long command I only entered once. Then I change my mind and hit ^U to clear (delete) the command, and herein lies the problem because that also deletes the line from the actual history file which I don't want. Is there any way to change this behavior?

I tried looking up answers, but every answer is about the exact opposite (i.e., how to delete commands from history). I just want to know if I can change the behavior so I can ^P to previous commands, clear the line with ^U if I happen to change my mind, and prevent the command from being deleted in history so that I can ^P to that same command again as I wish. The work around solution I know is hitting M-S-> (going to end of file) instead of clearing the line with ^U, but I don't want to use that key sequence.

I am on MacOS using iterm2 and oh-my-zsh.